# upgrading to windows 11 with "This PC can't run windows 11"

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-10-upgrade, tpm, windows-11

I'm trying to upgrade my windows 10 into 11 but I get this message from the PC health check program that my PC can't run windows 11, It has all of the requirements such as dx12, 12GB memory, Intel i5 2.6 GHz, but it doesn't have TPM support due to it being a little old, I tried enabling Secure Boot but windows refuse to boot while the secure boot is on and returns to boot selection page, is there another way to bypass the TPM requirement and if not, would it be possible to download the .iso file and choose the "upgrade" option in installation and force it that way?

Comment: A method for installing can be found in the article [https://winaero.com/how-to-install-windows-11-without-tpm-2-0/](https://winaero.com/how-to-install-windows-11-without-tpm-2-0), but I take no responsibility.

Comment: Why does everybody want to "upgrade" to a first-test beta, that will probably have major errors & cause thousands of amateur early adopters to lose their entire data. **Wait, people**. If you can't figure out the requirements, it's almost a certainty you won't figure out how to get back to your working OS.

Answer (score 1):

There is growing clarity about the requirements for Windows 11.

[Microsoft requirement for TPM](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/compatibility/windows-11/)

> Processor: 1 gigahertz (GHz) or faster with 2 or more cores on a
> compatible 64-bit processor or System on a Chip (SoC) RAM: 4 gigabyte
> (GB) Storage: 64 GB or larger storage device System firmware: Trusted
> Platform Module (TPM) version 2.0 Graphics card: Compatible with
> DirectX 12 or later with WDDM 2.0 driver S mode is only supported on
> Home edition of Windows 11. If you are running a different edition of
> Windows in S mode, you will need to first switch out of S mode prior
> to upgrading.

There had be some discussion about allowing TPM 1.2 but Microsoft has clarified this and only allows TPM 2

Run the GitHub tool and see what it says for you.

[GitHub Windows 11 check](https://www.windowscentral.com/whynotwin11-app-check-windows-11-hardware)

Want more detail as to why your PC may not get Windows 11? A new free app called WhyNotWin11 dives much deeper than Microsoft's own attempt.

> Windows 11 has strict CPU and hardware requirements that are causing a
> lot of frustration. Microsoft's own PC Health Check app is getting
> better but still feels half-baked. A new free, open-source app called
> WhyNotWin11 provides much more detail for users exploring their PC's
> hardware in preparation for Windows 11.

It also appears the CPUs older than 3 years will not run Windows 11. I have not yet seen clarity whether this is a soft or hard floor.

Comment: I have tried the tool and some of the requirements that I don't have are: wrong booth method Legacy that if I set it on UEFI only windows refuse to boot and returns to the boot menu same issue with secure boot that isn't enabled and if I turn it on windows won't boot, another issue is with my disk partition type and it says GPT not detected and for that I assume I have to remove the partition and remake it, and last one is that my pc doesn't have TPM chip installed, I don't think it be possible to update it through windows update I either have to do a clean install or upgrade through ISO file.

Comment: The machine is too old to run Windows 11 based on what we know now. Since you do not have the TPM chip (not uncommon for older machines) it is up to you whether you wish to correct UEFI because at the end, the computer still will not run Windows 11,

Comment: Thank you for the information and advices, then I have to stick with win10 until I'd be able to change my device.

Comment: Windows 10 end of life is now pegged at October 2025 so you do have ample time.